# Number of free homotopy classes < number of homotopy group elements

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm looking for a 'simple' path-connected space $X$ such that for some homotopy group $\pi_n(X)$ there are fewer *free homotopy classes* $[S^n,X]$ than elements of $\pi_n(X)$.

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200799/question-on-showing-a-bijection-between-pi-1x-x-0-and-s1-x-when-x-is) question we know that no such example can exist for $n=1$. EDIT: this is false! Thanks to Moishe Cohen. **Ideally I would like an example for $n=2$**.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, it does not follow and actually, such examples do exist for $n=1$. For instance, start with an infinite group $G$ which has exactly two conjugacy classes, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88980/infinite-group-with-only-two-conjugacy-classes)  (such examples exist even among finitely generated groups). Then let $X=K(G,1)$. Of course, maybe this $X$ does not qualify as "simple", but then you should explain what "simple" means.

Comment: Whenever $G=\pi_1(X)$ is a finite nonabelian group then $G$ has fewer conjugacy classes than elements and so $X$ has fewer elements in $[S^1,X]$ than elements of $\pi_1(X)$.

Comment: You should clarify what "fewer" means, my interpretation is that you are comparing cardinalities. Then as an example for $n\ge 2$ take the wedge of $S^n$ with uncountably many $S^1$'s.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks for the comment. By 'fewer' I am indeed referring to cardinalities, although if I am allowed to be picky I would prefer $[S^n,X]$ to be finite.

Answer (score 2):

Just to close this question:

Consider $n\ge 2$. Start with an $(n-1)$-connected space $Y$ such that $\pi_n(Y)$ is finite, $\cong {\mathbb Z}_k$, say, attach $n+1$-cell to $S^n$ along a degree $k$ map, $k>1$. Take $X= S^1\vee Y$.

Then $[S^n, X]\cong \pi_n(Y)\cong {\mathbb Z}_k$ is finite, while $\pi_n(X)$ is infinite, isomorphic to the countably infinite direct sum 
$$
\oplus_{i\in {\mathbb Z}} {\mathbb Z}_k.$$ 
The fundamental group of $X$ acts on this group as the shift.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by the OP, this is equivalent to having a nontrivial action of $\pi_1(X)$ on $\pi_n(X)$.

Comment: I see, thank you. This seems to be in tension with this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254666/bijection-between-the-free-homotopy-classes-sn-x-and-the-orbit-space-pi) however.

Comment: Right.  So then you answered your own question: take a space $X$ with a nontrivial action of the fundamental group on a higher homotopy group.